# check whether a checkbox in bootstrap-multiselect has been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to check in javascript whether a checkbox in bootstrap-multiselect has been checked. Usually checkboxes are created using the  label and the type="checkbox" attribute. In that case I can use

```
document.getElementById(id).checked
```

to test whether the checkbox is checked or not. But in bootstrap-multiselect, the  label is used. 
Here is my html code:

```
<select class="demo" multiple="multiple">
    <option id="test_id" value="test_value">test_value</option>
</select>
```

If I use the function document.getElementById(id).checked, I get an "undefined" instead of true or false? 
What is the correct way to test for a checked or unchecked box in this case?
thanks
carl

Comment: `id` in an option...that's new

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById(id).selected` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just push all the selected values into an array and manipulate the info as needed.

HTML

```
<select class="demo" multiple="multiple" >
  <option id="test_id1" value="test_value1">test_value1</option>
  <option id="test_id2" value="test_value2">test_value2</option>
  <option id="test_id3" value="test_value3">test_value3</option>
  <option id="test_id4" value="test_value4">test_value4</option>
</select>
<div id='selectedVals'></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".demo").change(function() {
  var allSelected = new Array();
  $(".demo option:selected").each(function(){
    allSelected.push(this.value);
  });
  $('#selectedVals').html(allSelected)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wa4mjmaj/

Comment: yes that certainly works, but is there also something like the checked attribute? A boolean would be great, even though I can solve my problem already with your solution above...

Comment: Generally speaking, it's uncommon to have inputs of type `checkbox` inside a `select` element. If you really want to have those elements your best route would be to mimic the `select` behavior with some type of dropdown housing all your `checkbox`. Take a look at this code example http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/hlmri

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that returns whether a specific option is checked using its id:

```
function isChecked(optionId) {
    return $(".demo > #" + optionId).get(0).selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle using JQuery. I assume you're using JQuery if you're using Bootstrap. Those are select options you have, not checkboxes, btw ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/d1L8uott/

Code:

```
<select class="demo" multiple="multiple" id="mySelect">
 <option id="test_id1" value="test_value">test_value1</option>
 <option id="test_id2" value="test_value">test_value2</option>
 <option id="test_id3" value="test_value">test_value3</option>
</select>

$('#mySelect').change(function(){
  alert($('#mySelect option:selected').text());
});
```